# getsockopt api design questions

Tags: c, linux, getsockopt

we can see the api is defined as blow

```
   int getsockopt(int sockfd, int level, int optname,
                  void *optval, socklen_t *optlen);
```

Question 1:

1. Suppose given a level and optname,  then we know the optlen, why do we need the user to provide the optlen parameter as well?
2. even user provide the optlen, why it is a pointer to socklen_t rather than socklen_t directly?  do the implementation will change the value of optlen somehow?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at the Linux man page for [`getsockopt(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getsockopt.2.html) or the POSIX specification of [`getsockopt()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getsockopt.html)?

1. The `optlen` parameter is an in-out parameter.  On input, it specifies how much space is available in the `optval` space, and on output, it reports how much of the space in `optval` was written to.
2. Yes, the implementation changes the value of `*optlen`.

For example, POSIX says:

> If the size of the option value is greater than *option_len*, the value stored in the object pointed to by the *option_value* argument shall be silently truncated. Otherwise, the object pointed to by the *option_len* argument shall be modified to indicate the actual length of the value.

The specification uses `option_len` where you used `optlen`, and `option_value` where you used `optval`.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to understand.Because api faces many options and needs to prepare for future options.

Example:

assume  "optname=1" , it will return 64bytes strings. At this time ,you need :

char optval[64];
socklen_t optlen=64;